# Android Bluetooth BroadcastReceiver not discovering devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have combed the forums in order to try and figure out why my bluetooth BroadcastReceiver isn't working and all I can find is people saying to ensure that coarse/fine location permissions are requested. I'm already doing that here (method is called before the discovery method):

**Request Permissions**

```
private void requestPermissions()
{
    final int CODE = 5; // app defined constant used for onRequestPermissionsResult

    boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;

    String[] permissionsToRequest =
            {
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            };

    for(String permission : permissionsToRequest)
    {
        allPermissionsGranted = allPermissionsGranted &&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    if(!allPermissionsGranted)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsToRequest, CODE);
    }
}
```

The problem is that my BroadcastReceiver never finds other discoverable devices, if a device is already paired, it puts it in a ListView as expected, but once the device is unpaired, it cannot identify it again. See screenshots below.

[Output with no paired devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEAnT.png)

[Output with paired devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZyHo.png)

I'm at a loss at this point, it feels like I've tried everything, if anyone has any ideas you'd save my life and I'd be eternally grateful.

Thanks,

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
        {
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if(btDevice.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
            {
                newDevicesArrayAdapter.add(btDevice.getName() + "\n" + btDevice.getAddress());
            }
        }
        else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))
        {
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);

            if(newDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0)
            {
                newDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                newDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**onCreate**  - Setup ListView elements and IntentFilters

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_machine);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

    pairedDevicesArrayAdapter   = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);
    newDevicesArrayAdapter      = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

    ListView pairedListView     = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);

    pairedListView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
    pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(deviceClickListener);
    newDevicesListView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
    newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(deviceClickListener);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

    filter              = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
}
```

**doDiscovery()** - Called by onStart method, I've verified that it gets called

```
private void doDiscovery()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

    requestPermissions();

    setTitle(R.string.scanning);

    findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()) { btAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); }

    newDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just being stupid and had values updating to both ListViews, so I never saw the list of other devices.

```
newDevicesListView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
```

Should have been:

```
newDevicesListView.setAdapter(newDevicesArrayAdapter);
```